# Expressing 'about' in Chinese

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-requests, sentence-structure, word

*Please use simplified characters.*

In English we sometimes say:

> 'My teacher taught us **about** Chinese'
>
> ‘My friend was telling me **about** Chinese'
>
> 'You're not intelligent enough to talk **about** complex Chinese grammar'
>
> 'The novel is **about** dragons'

All of these use the word **about**. I've wanted to express these kinds of sentences in Chinese for ages. How would I do it?

- Please explain how to express the word 'about' in Chinese.
- Please translate **or** create your own example sentences.

Comment: see dictionaries about 关于，where  E uses an intervening prep. C often uses none,  （１）我老师教我们汉语／中文，（２）我朋友谈到、讨论汉语。（３）你不是足够聪明可以讨论复杂汉语语法。（４）该小说是讲述龙的。 
Feed "关于，teach,tell,talk,is,are about" to jukuu, get lots of examples.

Comment: re comment #1: teach sth.≠ teach about sth.，as web search seems to show "teach sb. about sth." may not be part of standard English, (whereas "tell,talk,be about" are)

Answer (score 5):

[**About** + adjective phrase]= [**有关** + adjective phrase + **的**] or [**关于** + adjective phrase + **的**]

> 'My teacher taught us (knowledge) **about** Chinese'
>
> 我老师教我们**有关**中文**的** (知识)
>
> *'Chinese'(中文) is a part of the adjective phrase '中文的'*
>
> *The object '知识'(knowledge) can be omitted in English, but cannot be omitted in Chinese.*
>
> *有关 can also be omitted*: 我老师教我们中文**的** (知识)

~

> ‘My friend was telling me (things) **about** Chinese'
>
> 我朋友告诉我**有关**中国人**的**(事情)
>
> *'Chinese'(中国人) is a part of the adjective phrase '中国人的'*
>
> *The object '事情'(things) can be omitted in English, but cannot be omitted in Chinese.*
>
> *有关 can be omitted*: 我朋友告诉我中国人**的**(事情)

~

> 'You're not intelligent enough to talk **about** complex Chinese grammar'
>
> 你还没聪明到能够谈论**有关**复杂的中文语法**的**(程度)
>
> *'复杂的中文语法' (complex Chinese grammar) is a part of the adjective phrase '复杂的中文语法的'*
>
> *The object '程度'(level) can be omitted in English, but cannot be omitted in Chinese.*
>
> *有关 can be omitted* :你还没聪明到能够谈论复杂的中文语法**的**(程度)

~

> 'The novel is (a novel) **about** dragons'
>
> '这小说是**关于**龙**的**(小说)'
>
> *'龙'(dragons) is a part of the adjective phrase '龙的'*
>
> *Since the object 'novel'(小说) is the same as the subject, it can be omitted in both English and Chinese.*
>
> *有关 can not be  omitted here* -- because 龙 is a noun that can be either part of the adjective phrase or the subject. '这小说是龙**的**(小说)' could mean 'it is a novel about dragons' or 'dragons own this novel'

Comment: For a question about the chinese language, could you say 我有一個問題關於中文的語言 with 的語言 instead of 的知識？

Comment: @MuchAppreciated25  yes you can 語言 and 知識 are both noun